# Selecting an element using class and some other attribute in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Following is my code. I'm trying to select an element based on tow attributes , one a class using `.class` selector. and other using a data attribute `[data-depth='2']` .

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', ".node [data-depth='2']", function() {
  alert("clicked");
})
```

```css
.node {
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #EF4836;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="node" data-depth="2">
  Click me
</div>

<div class="node" data-depth="3">
  Do not Click me
</div>
```

But the element is not getting selected. What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space between `.node` and `[data-depth='2']`. Space means descendant elements of `.node` has attribute `data-depth="2"`.

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', ".node[data-depth='2']", function() {
    alert("clicked");
})
```

```css
.node {
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #EF4836;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="node" data-depth="2">
  Click me
</div>

<div class="node" data-depth="3">
  Do not Click me
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', "[data-depth='2'].node", function() {
  alert("clicked");
})
```

```css
.node {
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #EF4836;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="node" data-depth="2">
  Click me
</div>

<div class="node" data-depth="3">
  Do not Click me
</div>
```

It should have no space between them.
If there is space it will be looking `for the child` of the `class node`that has `[data-depth='2']`

Answer (score 0):

Another Method

This will have more of practical use:

HTML

Click me

```
 <div class="node" data-depth="3">
    Do not Click me
 </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).on('click', ".node", function() {
_this = $(this);
_depth = _this.data("depth");

  switch(_depth) {
   case 2: alert('clicked '+ 2);break;
   case 3: alert('clicked '+ 3);break;
   default : alert('clicked other')
  }
})
```